# Jquery - Using the result of an Ajax call in a FORM hidden field

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery script that uses Ajax to return data form a database. This works fine.

What I then would like to do is use the result in a hidden form field.

My Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    function runrequests() { 
       $.ajax({ 
         url: 'get_request_id.php',
         type:"POST",
         data:"alertID",

         dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){ 
            document.getElementById("alertid").innerHTML = data;
            } 
        });  
    };  

           // run it initially
    runrequests();

    // run it every 30 seconds
    setInterval(runrequests, 30 * 1000);
});
```

My Form:

```
<div id="alertid"></div>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
<input type="image" src="butler_request.png" name="roominput" id="roominput" value="Submit" />
<input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1" />
<input type="text" id="alertid" name="RecordID" value="value" />
</form>
```

Can anyone help, many thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi, When you say "here is no .innerHTML of input type text fields." what do you mean?

Comment: Hi all, many thanks for the help but none of the replies populate the hidden form filed, or am I mis understand something. How can I populate the form filed value with the result?

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't notice the hidden input didn't have an id, I updated my answer to include $("input[name=MM_update]") - also please note that IDs are unique, you have 2 elements with the same ID

Comment: Hi Chris, many thany for your time, it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. You need to set the val.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
function runrequests() { 
   $.post('get_request_id.php', {alertID:"alertID"}, function(data){ 
        $("input[name=MM_update]").val(data);
   }, 'json');  
};  

// run it initially
runrequests();

// run it every 30 seconds
setInterval(runrequests, 30 * 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() { 
    function runrequests() { 
       $.ajax({ 
         url: 'get_request_id.php',
         type:"POST",
         data:"alertID",

         dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){ 
            $("#alertid").val(data) ;   
            } 
        });  
    };  

           // run it initially
    runrequests();

    // run it every 30 seconds
    setInterval(runrequests, 30 * 1000);
});
</script>
```